# Convert header and values list to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets-api

I'm reading data from Google Sheets and was able to successfully get it in:

```
header = result.get('values', [])[0] #First line is column names
values = result.get('values', [])[1:] #Everything else is data
```

Then after that I'm doing this:

```
if not values:
    print('No data found.')
else:
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, columns=header)
    print(df.head(10))
```

but I'm getting an error:

> AssertionError: 26 columns passed, passed data had 14 columns

If I print header or values I'm getting the data in List successfully.

Comment: `len(values)` is `5297` and `len(header)` is `26`. I might not want to hard code it as the data will be added to it every now and then.

Comment: The amount of columns in `header` does not align with the amount of columns in `values`. Hence the 26 vs 14. Try this first `len(pd.DataFrame(data=values).columns)`.

Comment: The output of that is `14`. SO on google sheet `14` columns has data to them and columns from 15 to 26 does not have any data yet. But the column names are there, so pandas should just add blank to its values right?

Comment: That doesn't work that way: Can you try: `df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, columns=header[:14])`

Comment: This works perfectly. So what about the rest of the columns that are there but have no value? What should I do with them? Wait for the data or is there a way?

Comment: Could you maybe add the output of  `print(header)`, so I can make an answer for you?

Comment: here it is `['SB ID', 'Date of Survey', 'Country', 'Type', 'Cohort', 'Region', 'District', 'Sector', 'Village', 'Gender', 'Age (at time of survey)', 'TNS ID', 'Marital Status', 'Highest Education Level', 'Employment Status_after', 'Months Employed_after', 'Average Monthly Salary (USD)_after', 'Employer No. of Staff_after', 'Employer Registered?_after', 'Employer Sector_after', 'Employment Status_before', 'Months Employed_before', 'Average Monthly Salary (USD)_before', 'Employer No. of Staff_before', 'Employer Registered?_before', 'Employer Sector_before']`

Comment: Just out of curiosity how did you know that the columns will be 14 from 5297?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can make your dataframe with the present values, after that create a dataframe with the rest of the columns with `NaN` and `concat` them together:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, columns=header[:14])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({head : [np.NaN]*len(df) for head in header[14:]})

df_final = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

> Q: how did you know that the columns will be 14 from 5297

A: Because your values contains rows, so 5297 is the amount of rows in your data.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just want to share that where you've written `14` I've added `len(pd.DataFrame(data=values).columns)` so that I don't have to worry when the data is updated and it'll automatically pick the number of rows.

Comment: Yes, good point. And no problem, goodluck with Python and Pandas :)